# Coffeescript - How to call method of parent class

Tags: coffeescript

```
class Foo 
  foo: () ->
    console.log("foo method Called")

class Bar extends Foo
  constructor: () ->
    console.log("Bar created")

  bar: () ->
    console.log("bar method called")
    foo

b = new Bar
b.bar()
```

Results:
Bar created
bar method called
ReferenceError: foo is not defined

How do I call the foo method?

Comment: Have you tried with parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, you need to call `this.foo` (or `@foo`).

Second, in CoffeScript the last variable mentioned in a function definition is returned, not executed. So if you want to call that function your code needs to look like this:

```
bar: () ->
    console.log("bar method called")
    this.foo() // or @foo()
```

Otherwise without the `()` it will return the function rather than call it. Note that this will also compile to `return this.foo()`, so if you don't want to return anything, add a blank `return` on your last line.

Comment: Correct, but stylistically, most CoffeeScripters would write `@foo()` instead to call instance methods.

Comment: @AlexWayne Each to their own ;)

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple :)

Comment: @Michael: I'm pretty sure that without the parentheses the function is not called (executed), you're comparing `return foo;` with `return foo();` (where `typeof foo === 'function'`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@foo()`. `functions` declared in class are added to the class's `prototype`. Have a look at the javascript produced by the code [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%20%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%28%22foo%20method%20Called%22%29%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28%22Bar%20created%22%29%0A%0A%20%20bar%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28%22bar%20method%20called%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20this.foo%28%29%0Ab%20%3D%20new%20Bar%0Ab.bar%28%29)

To call the functions directly added to a function prototype, you will need `this`.